# Automatic inner margins in the flexbox model

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

This is a question about the new Flexible Box layout model.

Assume that inside a container with `display: flex;` I have two items. When the container is wide enough, both items are laid out horizontally, otherwise the flexbox layout mechanism will make them stack vertically. What I want is to have an inner margin between both items when they are next to each other, but I want this margin to vanish when they have to be stacked on top of each other.

Is this possible with the FlexBox model?

As an example, one can use the following document, which has been tested with a recent version of Chrome:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Flex Box</title>
<style>
    body {
        font-size: 100px;
    }
    .container {
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;  
        -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;    
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
</style>
<div class="container">
    <p>
        One
    </p>
    <p>
        Two
    </p>
</div>
```

​
When the outer div has enough horizontal space, "One" and "Two" are displayed next to each other with no space in between. As soon as one shrinks the browser window, both become stacked vertically. I would like to have both paragraphs separated by a margin while they are next to each other.

http://jsfiddle.net/WHYS2/

Answer (score 1):

This is only partially possible. You have to work with [Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/).

In the following example, the two boxes are next to each others, but when there is not enough space (for instace, the viewport of the browser is smaller than 800px) the boxes are among each other.

See this demo live at http://jsfiddle.net/tjNhF/ and resize your browser window.

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut dapibus tellus non dui eleifend viverra. Proin quis nunc purus. Suspendisse at quam nisl, nec posuere mi. Donec nec nisi eros. Fusce vel orci quam. Cras urna arcu, hendrerit in consequat in, faucibus vitae nulla. Donec a urna risus. Proin posuere. </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Nulla magna felis, facilisis vel adipiscing et, bibendum ac tellus. Pellentesque in risus in leo scelerisque adipiscing quis ut augue. Etiam luctus nisi sit amet nulla ullamcorper quis commodo purus volutpat. Sed est nisl, facilisis non vestibulum sed, auctor et odio. Aenean eget neque urna, a hendrerit ipsum. Sed sollicitudin.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@media all {
    body {
        background-color: #aaffaa;
    }

    .box {
        width: 100%;
        border: 1px solid #555;

        display: -webkit-box;
        -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;

        display: -moz-box;
        -moz-box-orient: horizontal;

        display: box;
        box-orient: horizontal;
    }

    .box > div {
        padding: 1em 5em;
        -webkit-box-flex: 1;
        -moz-box-flex: 1;
        box-flex: 1;
    }

    .box > div:nth-child(1){ background : #abc; }
    .box > div:nth-child(2){ background : #bca; }
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
    body {
        background-color: #ffaaaa;
    }

    .box {
        box-orient: vertical;
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    }
    .box > div {
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-right: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for setting up the demo. Using media queries is, of course, an option, but it will be less useful if I don't know the widths of the inner items. Also switching to vertical orientation "by hand" shouldn't be necessary as the flexbox model automatically begins to break down the main axis when there is not enough space along one line of that axis.

By the way, you are using the old flexbox model, but the current W3C recommendation probably doesn't add much in function.

Comment: Maybe you could add your existing code to your first post so we can adapt your code and your flexbox version.

Answer (score 0):

When the paragraphs are on the same line, do you want a fixed-width margin between them, and then any extra space in the line added to the right of the second paragraph? Or do you want the first pinned to the left and the second pinned to the right, with a variable-width margin in between? Do you want the paragraphs to have their widths be based on their content, as they are now?

When the paragraphs wrap to two lines, do you still want their widths to be based on their content, or do you want each to expand to fill 100% of its line?

Comment: For what I currently have in mind, the widths of the paragraphs should be based on their content and any extra space in the line should be added to the right of the second paragraph. (The same when the paragraphs are being wrapped to two lines, e.g. any extra space on the right.)